# Jquery UI draggable select item to be a draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="match_task_elements_31" class="match_task_draggables ui-draggable">
   <span class="match_task_draggable" id="match_task_draggable_17">Dach</span>
   <span class="match_task_draggable" id="match_task_draggable_16">Tschüss</span>
</div>
```

Now I want that each span is a dragable object that I can drag'n'drop

I tried this JS code:

```
$(".match_task_draggables").draggable({handle : '.match_task_draggable'});
```

But so the whole div with class match_task_draggables is a the block I can drag'n'drop

whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below. It allows to drag and drop the `span`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".match_task_draggable").draggable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="match_task_elements_31" class="match_task_draggables ui-draggable">
  <span class="match_task_draggable" id="match_task_draggable_17">Dach</span>
  <span class="match_task_draggable" id="match_task_draggable_16">Tschüss</span>
</div>
```